# Typescript, как правильно выполнить преобразование типа?

Tags: typescript

**Суть:**

Есть сервис `User` и сервис базы данных (обертка, через которую все сервисы работают с базой. То есть, сервис `User` получает массив юзеров через `postgres`) `Postgres`.

Для примера, возьмем метод `find`.

Возвращаемый тип от сервиса `postgres`: `[EntityClassOrSchema[], number]`. Значение: `[[объект из бд], всего объектов]`.

В сервисе `User`, что запрашивает объекты через сервис `postgres`, хочу сделать привидение типа на: `User[]`

На что получаю ошибку:

```
TS2352: Conversion of type 'Promise<[EntityClassOrSchema[], number]>' to type 'Promise<User[]>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.   Type '[EntityClassOrSchema[], number]' is not comparable to type 'User[]'.
```

**Вопросы:**

- Нужно ли делать привидение типа тут, вообще?
- Как его приводить, не через `unknown`, же.

**Update:**

По семантике, даже не `User[]`, а `[User[], number]`

**Update 2:**

Типы:
[EntityClassOrSchema](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/master/lib/interfaces/entity-class-or-schema.type.ts), тип [User](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities) это `Entity` из `typeorm`.

**Update 3:**

[Пример кода:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5899.jpg)

P.S Декоратор `@Inject` подставит экземпляр класса `PostgresqlWrapper`.

Логика проста. Сервис `User`, на ряду с другими сервисами, через обертку (`PostgresqlWrapper` (чтобы при малейших изменениях не переписывать весь проект)) получает объекты из бд. Но вот тип ответа из сервиса `User` должен быть именно `User`, а не "какие-то объекты из бд" (тип от ответа из postgresqlWrapper)

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду говоря "выполнить преобразование типа?"?

Comment: `[EntityClassOrSchema[], number]` as `[User[], number]`

Comment: что за тип `EntityClassOrSchema` и как объявлен тип `User`?

Comment: `EntityClassOrSchema`: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/master/lib/interfaces/entity-class-or-schema.type.ts, тип `User` это `Entity` из `typeorm` https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities

Comment: Добавь это в вопрос.

Comment: Добавь пример своего кода, что и как ты получаешь и как именно приводишь. Пока выглядит так, будто все работает как надо, без ошибок.

Comment: @Grundy, Добавил.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130436/discussion-between-grundy-and-lasna1).